# How to update media player to play new file

Tags: android, media-player, updates

I have a section of code shown below that gets the pathname for an mp3 audio file stored in the content provider database.  Next it uses this pathname to load the mp3 file and start playing it.  The problem is that if I get a different pathname and hit pause or play it keeps playing the same old audio file, not the new file.  What is the best way to solve this problem?

```
      String pathName; // pathname of audio file stored in SD card
      String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + pathName +"'";
      String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE };
      cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

      if(cursor!=null){
         cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        musicName = (String) cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE));

         Toast.makeText(AudioService.this, "from　AUDIOSERVICE CLASS music name: " + musicName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         cursor.close();    

         player.setDataSource(musicName);

        player.prepare();

        player.start();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if path is same then play same file again and if file path is different then first reset mediaplayer and then play new file change your code as:

```
      String pathName=""; // pathname of audio file stored in SD card
       public static String musicName="";
      String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + pathName +"'";
      String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE };
      cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.
             Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

      if(cursor!=null){
         cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

if(musicName.length()==0){
         musicName = (String) cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                                      MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE));

         Toast.makeText(AudioService.this, 
                                    "from　AUDIOSERVICE CLASS music name:
                                      " + musicName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         cursor.close();    

         player.setDataSource(musicName);

        player.prepare();

        player.start();

  }
else{
 String musicNametemp = (String) cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                                          MediaStore.Images.Media.LATITUDE));

if(musicNametemp.equals(musicName)){

///play old music here
}

else{
//reset mediaplayer here

if(player !=null){
 player.reset();
 player.release();
 player = new MediaPlayer();

}
cursor.close();    
musicName=musicNametemp;
player.setDataSource(musicName);

player.prepare();

player.start();
}

}
```

Comment: good idea,  i will probably use some sort of change listener to check if the value of the variable has changed

Comment: @Kevik : yes just use an another variable to check if file path is same or not and reset `MediaPlayer` instance according to path